# ViewModel passed into WebApi method is null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-web-api

Not sure why I am having problems with this. I have done it before but looking at previous projects has yielded no help. I am sure that I am missing a configuration or something.

I have an ApiController in a WebForms 4.5 project that I am using to retrieve and update data from a datastore (SQL Server CE 4.0).

I have defined the following POST method to handle the adding of property records to a product ...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddPropertyToProduct([FromBody]ProductPropertyViewModel prodProp)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ProductPropertyViewModel, ProductProperty>();
        ProductProperty property = Mapper.Map<ProductProperty>(prodProp);

        ProductRepository.Instance.AddProperty(property.ProductId, property);
        ProductRepository.Instance.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The ProductPropertyViewModel argument is a ViewModel that I use instead of the Data Model...

```
public class ProductPropertyViewModel
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public Int64 ProductId { get; set; }

    public String PropertyName { get; set; }

    public String PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public String Comments { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

The client-side script that calls the service sends in a JSON string that matches the  ViewModel property for property...

```
var addPropertyToProduct = function (propertyViewModel, productId, isAsync, fnSuccess, fnError) {

    var methodUrl = "/api/ProductPropertyAPI/AddPropertyToProduct/"
    var ret = null;
    //
    // Make sure that the ProductId is specified as part of the ViewModel
    propertyViewModel.ProductId = productId;
    //
    // make sure that the propertyViewModel is reduced to JSON for being passed to the server.
    // Example : {"Id": 0, "ProductId":5,"PropertyName":"Engine Size","PropertyValue":"300cc","Comments":"Some comment","DateAdded":"07/25/2013","DateUpdated":"07/25/2013"}
    var jsonData = ko.toJSON(propertyViewModel);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonData,
        async: isAsync,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        url: methodUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            //#region console log
            var logMsg = "AJAX.ProductPropertyAPI.AddPropertyToProduct ( "+ JSON.stringify(jsonData) +" ): RESPONSE : " + JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(logMsg);
            //#endregion
            if (typeof fnSuccess === 'function') {
                fnSuccess(data);
            }
            else {
                defaultSuccess(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {

            if (typeof fnError === 'function') {
                fnError(data);
            }
            else {
                defaultError(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when the request is POSTED to the ***AddPropertyToProduct*** method of the service, the ***prodProp*** argument is NULL instead of an instance of the ViewModel. It was my understanding that the WebAPI would know to map the JSON data to the ProductPropertyViewModel object.

I am sure that I have overlooked something here but cannot figure out what it is. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks,
G

**UPDATE: Added Fiddler data**

This is the Request that I am sending via Fiddler.

```
POST http://localhost:55556/api/ProductPropertyAPI/AddPropertyToProduct HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:55556
ContentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
Content-Length: 155

{"Id": 0, "ProductId":5,"PropertyName":"Engine Size","PropertyValue":"300cc","Comments":"Some comment","DateAdded":"07/25/2013","DateUpdated":"07/25/2013"}
```

**UPDATED : Added $.Ajax Request Header from IE Developer Tools**

```
Key Value
Request POST http://localhost:55556/api/ProductPropertyAPI/AddPropertyToProduct/ HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:55556/Admin/ProductManager.aspx
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host    localhost:55556
Content-Length  129
DNT 1
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Pragma  no-cache
Cookie  __atuvc=38%7C8; __AntiXsrfToken=63a0ede574be4aa9a19e153474320450; ASPSESSIONIDACBTCRRS=FDDPEJIBPDFEODAHOEMBOOFK; ASPSESSIONIDCABTDTRT=AANBPPFCEFOBMAEFMMPMMFLF; ASPSESSIONIDAAARDSRS=LODHOFGCLJILEEEHICHGLNLA; ASPSESSIONIDCCDTCSQT=NHOJPJGCOECNJBIDGGKIALFG; ASP.NET_SessionId=xh4xctv0mvq2zb454hkb1f3z
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[FromBody]` attribute?

Comment: Yeah ... one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Can you use something like fiddler to inspect the post. Double check the content type and make sure the Json is something that can be mapped into your viewmodel. You can also try adding `dataType: "json"` to your ajax method.

Comment: Yep ... I have been doing that. I have added an example of a Fiddler request to the OP.

Comment: Looking at your Fiddler trace, the header is supposed to be `Content-Type` and not `ContentType`...so Web Api thinks that there is no content-type header in the request and doesn't deserialize as it doesn't know which formatter to use to deserialize and hence it creates a default value for the type here..which would be null in your case...weird that $.ajax doesn't set the correct header..

Comment: Latest Web API release bits throw back an error (415 status code) for these kind of scenarios so that it helps in figuring out the issue much sooner!

Comment: You're sending JSON, how is the default model binder to figure that out? You need to capture it and deserialize it into that view model. Would just be easier if you posted a form instead of JSON.

Comment: I am POSTING using AJAX. I don't want to postback the entire page. I have changed the Content-Type in Fiddler, still no luck. I have also checked the $.ajax request header and the Keys seems to all be correct. I have added the request header from $.ajax to the OP.

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copy pasted your code in to new project, and it failed.

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"
```

I'm assuming you're getting this same error. But after i removed:

```
contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
```

It worked.

My full ajax request:

```
// I used static jsonData because you're getting the correct values in 
// your fiddler so this is definitely not causing any issues
var jsonData = { "Id": 0, "ProductId": 5, "PropertyName": "Engine Size", "PropertyValue": "300cc", "Comments": "Some comment", "DateAdded": "07/25/2013", "DateUpdated": "07/25/2013" };
var methodUrl = "/api/test/AddPropertyToProduct/";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    //async: isAsync,
    //contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    url: methodUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success: ', data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error: ', data);
    }
});
```

The action method I used:

```
[HttpPost]
public string AddPropertyToProduct(ProductPropertyViewModel prodProp)
{
    return prodProp.PropertyName;
}
```

Comment: You are correct about the error message and also about removing the contentType from the Ajax request (although I don't understand why that's a problem, in fact I thought that it was necessary).  The *prodProp* parameter is no longer NULL, but it is also not loaded with the data I am trying to pass in. It is loaded with default values for each of the fields (strings are null, int64 is 0 and DateTime are 1/1/0001 12:00:00AM) rather than loading the JSON into the object instance.

Comment: Pretty sure that contentType is used in asp webform webmethods, but you don't need it in web api. As for default values: is your fiddler still sending the correct data? In my test, my function was returning the same thing I was sending it, which in the above example, was 'Engine Size'.

Comment: I marked this as the answer since it resolved the NULL problem, I still don't understand why the instance that IS being passed to the service function is full of default values. I will keep looking into it. My gut tells that there s still some backwoods config setting that is missing.